# Loop Iterative Program Correctness Example - Loop Invariants and Program Termination

Tags: python, correctness, proof-of-correctness

I need help proving the correctness of an iterative program:

```
def term_ex_2(x,y):
 ''' Pre: x and y are natural numbers '''
 a = x
 b = y
 while a >= 0 or b >= 0:
     if a > 0:
         a -= 1
     else:
         b -= 1
 return x * y
```

I know that I need to somehow find a loop invariant and prove it by induction on a loop. The problem is that the if/else statements here confuse me on how to come up with one.

I also have to prove whether the program terminates or not after that.

I have a general understanding on what the step by step process is but I don't know where to start on this example from the homework.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in **every** iteration of your outer `while` loop, either `a` or `b` decreases by 1.

Since `x` and `y` are assumed to be natural numbers, both of them are initially `> 0`.

**Loop Invariant:** `a >= 0` (Other possibilities might be there!)

Also, the program **does not** terminate, which is quite evident from the loop invariant above as it forces the `while` loop to evaluate to `true` always.

**Proof sketch:** As long as `a > 0`, the loop keeps on decrementing `a` till it reaches `0`. Then the `else` condition starts executing which continues to decrement `b` forever as `a == 0` makes the `while` loop iterate again and again.

Classic use of putting a *loop invariant* itself in the loop termination condition to make the loop *loop* infinitely!

Comment: Would b>=0 also be a loop invariants?

Comment: Feel free to ask for any further clarifications!

Comment: In my homework, I realized another question said to prove that loop invariants for this function is a, b >=0 which is why I asked. I thought b>=0 is a valid invariants because it’s one of the loop conditions

Comment: Also I have a couple other questions in loop invariants I am having trouble with like loops with if/else statements. Can you help me with a question like that?

Comment: By definition loop invariance is a condition which always evaluates to true at the start of the loop, irrespective of number of iterations. As you can see, once `a` reaches `0`, then only the `else` part executes and `b` keeps decrementing even below 0.

Comment: You can just directly run the code and print variable values to see if `a, b >=0` is satisfied. It is not in this case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224475/discussion-between-swag2198-and-dew-man7).